# WPF layout created dynamically using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, mvvm, rectangles

I'm trying to postion views to the window in layout which is rectangle base while using MVVM pattern.

In WinForms I was able to use width, height, x and y of rectagle to position controls easily by just setting same properties on control.

Now I'm rewriting this code to wpf using MVVM and I'm lost.

this is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

This is something I thought might work but it does not.

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VirtualScreens}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Grid.Row="{Binding Row}" Grid.Column="{Binding Column}" Content="{Binding Name}"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

public class VirtualScreen : ObservableObject
{
    string name;
    int row;
    int column;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    public int Row
    {
        get { return row; }
        set
        {
            row = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Row);
        }
    }

    public int Column
    {
        get { return column; }
        set
        {
            this.column = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Column);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any type of help

Comment: Sorry, but you'll need to provide some more details, or perhaps a screenshot of the WinForms application to give us a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: please read ["How To Ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: Grids can be laid out like this, and they automatically resize content with the window.  Canvases use the x,y,w,h coordinate system to lay out controls, but they require you to update layouts on window resizing.  Try creating a small prototype before asking a question, can prevent unwanted downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [WPF Grid](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) to layout the elements as shown in your UI. A three-row, three-column grid would work fine for you:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition /> 
        <RowDefinition /> 
        <RowDefinition /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">This is the big top left section</Button>
     <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">Top right</Button>
     <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">Middle right</Button>
     <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">Bottom left</Button>
     <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">Bottom center</Button>
     <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">Bottom right</Button>
</Grid>
```

Checkout [Grid Row and Column Spanning](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-column-row-span/) for more info.

Comment: This is what I would like to do dynamically using MVVM.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. "Dynamically using MVVM" - you mean you want to create this layout in code?

Answer (score 2):

you could use ItemsControl ItemsPanel, ItemsTemplate and ItemContainerStyle.

Here is an example for you

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding VirtualScreens}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```